# Crashlytics SFSafariViewController setIsInitLanguageConfigSet crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a weird crash reported by Crashlytics:

> [SFSafariViewController setIsInitLanguageConfigSet:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x100d75fb0

The crash happens in a class that doesn't contain anything related to SFSafariViewController, It's just a simple page containing 3 options related to which language a user wants the app to be localized to.

Has anyone experienced such crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was Facebook SDK that was causing this issue.
Updating to the latest version fixed it.